# Class 2D array turns to arr [] when called by function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, oop

I have a university assignment and I am completely confused on how to pass the array correctly to prevent the array from being passed as a single array and not a 2D array.

We are to create a random maze generator that will allow us to play that maze too. We are using a specialized windows code to display the maze, but that's not were the problem is so Ill leave that out
My lecturer gave us the skeleton code to work from. What must I change to get it to work?

We have not learnt dynamic memory location or vectors. We have to use an array. Please Help!!?

Here is his code:
I have used the same and just added all the function parameters. I have not changed anything with 'maze' though

```
class MazeSquare
{
    public:
    bool leftWall, rightWall, bottomWall, topWall;
    bool visited;
    int steps;

    MazeSquare() // constructor
    {
        Initialise();
    }

    void Initialise(void) // reinitialise a square for a new maze
    {
        leftWall = true; // create the maze square with all the walls
        rightWall = true;
        bottomWall = true;
        topWall = true;
        visited = false; // the robot has not visited the square yet
        steps = 256; // greater than maximum possible number of steps
    }
};

// constants
const int MAZE_SIZE = 16;

// function prototypes
void CreateMaze(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]);
void SolveMaze(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]);
void RestartMaze(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]);
void MoveRobot(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE], int &x, int &y, Point click);
void DrawWindow(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE], int x, int y);

int ccc_win_main() // main function for a graphics program
{
    MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]; // maze design
    int x = 0, y = 0; // robot position
    bool exit = false; // flag to control end of program
    // initialise the random number generator
    srand((unsigned int)(time(NULL)));
    /* initialise the window coordinates here */
    CreateMaze(maze); // create a new maze
    DrawWindow(maze); // draw the image in the GUI window
    do
    {
        // get a mouse click
        Point click = cwin.get_mouse("Click a button or move the robot");
        // handle the different types of mouse clicks
        if (/* new button is clicked */)
        {
            CreateMaze(maze);
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        if (/* solve button is clicked */)
        {
            SolveMaze(maze);
        }
        if (/* restart button is clicked */)
        {
            RestartMaze(maze);
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        if (/* exit button is clicked */)
        {
            exit = true;
        }
        // handle robot moves
        if (/* maze is clicked */)
        {
            MoveRobot(maze, x, y);
        }
        DrawWindow(maze);
    } while (!exit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: newlines and space won't increase size of your executable

Comment: Firstly: I have been paying attention all the time in his class. Dont have facebook or twitter and dont play any simple games. Secondly: There is nothing like this on the net. So helping me will also be able to help other people that might have the same problem. (Yes I have searched around and tried a whole lot of things) Thirdly: He has not EVER spoken about it. I know because I'd have it in written notes. (Yes, I'm one of those who have no life outside of  Uni)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusion number one - You cannot pass arrays to functions in C++.

Confusion number two - You cannot declare arrays as function parameters in C++

Confusion number three - 2D arrays are single arrays, a 2D array is an arrays of arrays, therefore it's a 'single array` also. I guess I'm saying the term single array doesn't have much meaning.

Arrays are a confusing topic in C++. You cannot do everything you might expect to be able to do with them. Instead everything is done with pointers. The relationship beween arrays and pointers in C++ is another confusing topic. You really need to read a book. Any specific questions, ask again.

But on the bright side I don't see anything particularly wrong with your code. You're certainly are not passing single arrays to your functions, as you are worried about.

EDIT:

Perhaps I should make this a little clearer. On point two, this code

```
void CreateMaze(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]);
```

certainly *looks* like you are declaring a function with an array parameter. But it doesn't. Instead the compiler takes the code and converts it into the equivalent code that uses pointers.

On point one, this code

```
CreateMaze(maze); // create a new maze
```

certainly *looks* like you are passing an array to a function, but again you are not. Given that code the compiler passes a pointer to the first element of your maze array, it doesn't pass the array itself.

Comment: But thats the problem. I am not passing single arrays and yet when I debug it comes back with an error at the return statement of main and says "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'maze' was corrupted."

Comment: @user2875423 Well that's just a bug. Nothing to do with the way you are passing parameters to your functions. Probably (definitely) you are accessing memory you are not supposed to.

Comment: If I set break points then when my array is passed to, lets say CreateMaze(maze), then the array goes from being 2 dimensional to being 1 dimensional. Instead of having 0x0.leftwall=false and then 0x1.leftwall = false. It is, 0.leftwall = false and 1.leftwall false. as if I only declared maze[] not maze[][]

Comment: what should I then change to make it work? Where is my error?

Comment: To be precise it goes to a pointer to an array. But that is supposed to happen.

Comment: Your error will be somewhere in one of the maze functions. But since you haven't posted those it's hard to say where. Carry on using the debugger, and don't worry too much that your arrays have all turned into pointers.

Comment: Quote 'As if I only declared [] not [][]'. That's right `void CreateMaze(MazeSquare maze[MAZE_SIZE][MAZE_SIZE]);` is really `void CreateMaze(MazeSquare (*maze)[MAZE_SIZE]);` In the second version `maze` is a pointer. Like I said you cannot declare array parameters in C++.

Comment: @user2875423 I don't know where your error is, it's in one of the maze functions. Since you haven't posted those I have no idea where. Carry on using the debugger to find the error. I'm *guessing* that the problem will be that you are accessing memory outside your maze, your code is falling off the edge of the maze and accessing memory it shouldn't. But only a guess.

Comment: @user2875423 It could easily be a miniscule error, that's all it takes.

Comment: BTW using the debugger, and looking at how your maze looks from the debugger, might give you some intuition about how arrays and functions work in C++.